# Prove that a certain limit doesn't exist

Tags: limits

I've been looking for the answer for several hours but hadn't come up with a solution.

I need to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}\cos (\frac 1 {x^2})$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Let $t\to 1/x^2$.  What is the limit, if it exists, $\lim_{t\to\infty}\cos(t)$?

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, your answers were really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $\cos(2n\pi)=1$ and $\cos((2n+1)\pi)=-1$ for all integers $n$.

Consider the two null sequences $x_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\pi}}, y_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi}}$.

Note that for your function $f$, $f(x_n)=1$ and $f(y_n)=-1$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Thus the limit cannot exist.

Answer (score 2):

As $x$ approaches zero, $1/x^2$ diverges and $$\cos\frac1{x^2}$$ covers the interval $[-1,1]$ infinitely many times. Therefore the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x_{n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ and $y_{n}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n+(\pi/3)}}$, and we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos(1/x_{n}^{2})=1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos(1/y_{n}^{2})=1/2$, so the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Work out two (or more) sequences $(x_n)$ converging to $0$, and for which $\cos x_n$ takes a constant, different, value.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f(x)=\cos\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$$
and define the sequence
$$u_n=(n\pi)^{-1/2}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
but

$$f(u_n)=(-1)^n\;\text{doesn't have a limit.}$$